# load image from url renders in very bad quality

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

i'm using [kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) for asynchronous loading of images. i've set up a server with a image in different sizes, to test the quality of the image inside the imageView. However whatever size i use (the image i use is vector graphic, so can be converted to all sizes) it still become very low quality inside the imageview. What is the best practice for storing such image on server side so it will be good quality in the imageview?

**imageView**

```
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/media/static/img/currencies/bitcoin_uzSOQkH.png")
let currencyImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35))
currencyImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

**image**

[image]

Comment: have you tried to set contentMode of imageView

Comment: i've even tried center which makes it better quality, but still no where near the actual image on my computer or when i access the image from server

Comment: Have you tried using the `options:` parameter on the `setImage(with:)` function which accepts `KingfisherOptionsInfo`, an option of which is `scaleFactor`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not kf's fault. On the server, just store a image with higher resolution. For a **35*35** image view. You need a **@3x** sized image which is **105*105** pixels to look good in all devices.